# JavaScript - SQL Reporting Services

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, reporting

Can We insert javascript in a report rendered by sql reporting services?

eg:- when mouse over happens over a cell i would like to open a div as in case of ajax modal popup control usage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, adding JavaScript and jQuery is completely doable with the results of a SQL query.  We have taken the results and looped through them to build up a string that can assign a DIV or CLASS to the rows, columns, or cells. Then apply hover effects to them for the final rendering in your script.  We did this for conditional highlighting and conditional hiding of data based on values, along with hover effects for fading in a color on the row/column being hovered upon.

It is not that hard, but it also may not be the most efficient way to do it considering the chance your query results may be hundreds and hundreds of rows.

I would say doable, but check for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen it done and don't exactly like the idea, but here is some information that I dredged up concerning javascript and Reporting Services.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170514231429/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mnf/archive/2007/11/25/sql-server-reporting-services-notes.aspx)